# Marking the checkbox as disabled or enabled at run time

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a `boolean` variable and if it is `true` I want to set some checkboxes to **disabled**
I was able to make my **input text boxes** `readonly` by using this inside my HTML for the text box:

```
readonly ="<%# myIsReadOnly %>"
```

But `checkboxes` don't have that.  So wanted to make them disabled if that variable is true.
How do I do that? I am also on `VB` language.
The example of CheckBox I have is something like this:

```
<input type = checkbox" name="blah" id="blah"/>
```

[image]

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya hmm? what?  code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually stick in server-side code to render both attribute and value.

```
<input type="checkbox" <%= myIsReadOnly ? "disabled='disabled'" : "" %> />
```

Comment: haven't tried yet but are you sure DISABLED can accept true false? I think my IDE gives error, it cannot accept true false for disabled.

Comment: Setting disabled to true false is valid. You can either set `.attr('disabled', true)` or `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')`. For remove `.attr('disabled', false)` or remove disable attribute.  Please google first before down-voting an answer.

Comment: hi, please see the screen shot I added to my question, VS says I can't use true false on disabled.  :(

Comment: also for tests, right now still I added a disabled = "false"  to it and still made it disabled, which means it doesn't work.

Comment: My previous answer was based on ***jQuery*** which sets `disabled="disabled"` under the hood. You cannot assign true/false value to ***disabled*** html attribute directly. Anyhow, I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.